# I built the Kivymd android app with buildozer and the app crashes after loading screen

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I built the app with buildozer and the app crashes after loading screen.

log for logcat search my package name

```
https://pastebin.com/BpNPsJme
```

source code (with buildozer spec file)

```
https://github.com/jeong-jimin-github/quiz
```

I added pillow to the requirements and installed another OS to build it, but it's the same.
sorry for my bad english